# How to force a running program to flush the contents of its I/O buffers to disk with external means?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, io, flush

I have a long-running C program which opens a file in the beginning, writes out "interesting" stuff during execution, and closes the file just before it finishes. The code, compiled with `gcc -o test test.c` (gcc version 5.3.1.) looks like as follows:

```
//contents of test.c
#include<stdio.h>

FILE * filept;

int main() {
    filept = fopen("test.txt","w");
    unsigned long i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1152921504606846976; ++i) {
        if (i == 0) {//This case is interesting!
            fprintf(filept, "Hello world\n");
        }
    }
    fclose(filept);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that *since this is a scientific computation* (think of searching for primes, or whatever is your favourite hard-to-crack stuff) it could really run for a *very* long time. Since I determined that I am not patient enough, I would like to abort the current computation, but I would like to do this in an *intelligent* way by somehow forcing the program *by external means* to flush out all the data that is currently in the OS buffer/disk cache, wherever.

Here is what I have tried (for this bogus program above, and of course not for the real deal *which is currently still running*):

1. pressing ctrl+C; or
2. sending `kill -6 <PID>` (and also `kill -3 <PID>`) -- as suggested by @BartekBanachewicz,

but after either of these approaches the file `test.txt` created in the very beginning of the program *remains empty*. This means, that the contents of `fprintf()` were left in some intermediate buffer during the computation, waiting for some OS/hardware/software flush signal, but since no such a signal was obtained, the contents *disappeared*. This also means, that the comment made by @EJP

> Your question is based on a fallacy. 'Stuff that is in the OS
>   buffer/disk cache' won't be lost.

does not seem to apply here. Experience shows, that stuff indeed get lost.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I am willing to attach a debugger to this process if it is possible, and if it is safe to retrieve the data this way. Since I never done such a thing before, I would appreciate if someone would provide me a *detailed* answer how to get the contents flushed into the disk *safely and surely*. Or I am open to other methods as well. There is no room for error here, as I am not going to rerun the program again.

Note: Sure I could have opened and closed a file *inside* the `if` branch, but that is extremely inefficient once you have *many* things to be written. Recompiling the program is not possible, as it is still in the middle of some computation.

Note2: the original question was asked the same question in a slightly more abstract way related to C++, and was tagged as such (that is why people in the comments suggesting `std::flush()`, which wouldn't help even if this was a C++ question). Well, I guess I made a major edit then.

---

Somewhat related: [Will data written via write() be flushed to disk if a process is killed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647997/will-data-written-via-write-be-flushed-to-disk-if-a-process-is-killed)

Comment: How about asking the program to exit nicely instead of killing it?

Comment: Looking for [std::flush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush)?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz that  actually might work... so I should send the program a different `SIG...` signal. I will check.

Comment: Do you want to force flush when you kill the program?

Comment: @nwp (and the comment-upvoters): I don't see how `std::flush` would help since the program is *still running*.

Comment: [Is the fact that the program hangs intended behavior?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Matsmath What about "This manipulator may be used to produce an incomplete line of output immediately, e.g. when displaying output from a **long-running process**" is unclear to you?

Comment: @Matsmath It means that you should modify your program so that it flushes after writing interesting stuff, or periodically, or whatever. Since your question mentions opening/closing a file each time, it seems changes to the program are fair game. Or are you asking how to extract the data from one particular currently running instance which you don't want to kill?

Comment: @Matsmath doesn't even have to be a signal, you can just wait on stdio.

Comment: Your question is based on a fallacy. 'Stuff that is in the OS buffer/disk cache' won't be lost. What you have to worry about is stuff that is still in the application, e.g. `stdio` or `streams` buffers, and `fflush()` and `std::flush()` are the answers to those two.

Comment: You can use `std::flush` while the program is running. Flushing when the program is not running doesn't make sense.

Comment: @To the commenters who are repeatedly suggesting `std::flush`. Where should I put that? I have a process which is *currently* running *at this moment*.

Comment: @EJP so I guess you are suggesting basically the same idea as of Bartek B: gracefully shut down the process, if possible. I guess if I just plug the plug out of the wall, those stuff in the OS buffer/disk cache *will* be lost.

Comment: The real solution is to troubleshoot why your program runs "forever" or, if the "interesting stuff" is available quickly but the program is doing something else for very long after that, split it into two programs.

Comment: Since you're asking for ways to intrude into the program with OS means, please specify the OS.

Comment: I made a major edit. It is somewhat unfortunate that I have changed the scope from C++ to C.

Comment: "Experience shows, that stuff indeed get lost." - How are you determining that?

Comment: "but after either of these approaches the file test.txt created in the very beginning of the program remains empty." I checked that with `cat`. You are right in the sense that stuff might get lost from the `stdio`, or `streams` buffers, and not from the disk/os cache.

Comment: Yup - disk cache is independent of process lifecycle.  Only place you can be losing data is if you're not writing it in the first place (due to a bug), or you're not flushing it from your streams (which can be solved with `fflush` or `std::flush` at the appropriate time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can I just add some clarity? Obviously months have passed, and I imagine your program isn't running any more ... but there's some confusion here about buffering which still isn't clear.

As soon as you use the *stdio* library and `FILE *`, you will by default have a fairly small (implementation dependent, but typically some KB) buffer inside your program which is accumulating what you write, and flushing it to the OS when it's full, (or on file close). When you kill your process, it is this buffer that gets lost.

If the data *has* been flushed to the OS, then it is kept in a unix file buffer until the OS decides to persist it to disk (usually fairly soon), or someone runs the `sync` command. If you kill the power on your computer, then this buffer gets lost as well. You probably don't care about this scenario, because you probably aren't planning to yank the power! But this is what @EJP was talking about (re *Stuff that is in the OS buffer/disk cache' won't be lost*): your problem is the *stdio* cache, not the OS.

In an ideal world, you'd write your app so it fflushed (or `std::flush()`) at key points. In your example, you'd say:

```
    if (i == 0) {//This case is interesting!
        fprintf(filept, "Hello world\n");
        fflush(filept);
    }
```

which would cause the *stdio* buffer to flush to the OS. I imagine your real writer is more complex, and in that situation I would try to make the fflush happen "often but not too often". Too rare, and you lose data when you kill the process, too often and you lose the performance benefits of buffering if you are writing a lot.

In your described situation, where the program is already running and can't be stopped and rewritten, then your only hope, as you say, is to stop it in a debugger. The details of what you need to do depend on the implementation of the std lib, but you can usually look inside the `FILE *filept` object and start following pointers, messy though. @ivan_pozdeev's comment about executing `std::flush()` or `fflush()` within the debugger is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your time writing up this detailed... *attempt* of an answer. My program is still running, by the way. I have decided it is better not to mess with it.

Comment: @Matsmath OMG! really? Wow! Do you know, I don't think I'd touch it either... :-)

Comment: I need to trigger the flush externally for stdout file redirect. The program is started like `./program > out.txt`. Is it possible to somehow get the reference of that file and call `fflush` externally (without modifiing the program of course)?

Comment: @Mvorisek sorry, don't think so. The buffer is just some memory inside the process (it's not an OS thing), and if the program hasn't been written with a "flush on demand" capability (via signal handler etc), then it can't do it. My normal trick when I find process logging is overly buffered is to do something that stimulates extra logging and it will flush on buffer-full, but that won't work on everything. Debugger, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

By default, the response to the signal SIGTERM is to shut down the application immediately. However, you can add your own custom signal handler to override this behaviour, like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <atomic>
...
std::atomic_bool shouldStop;

...
void signalHandler(int sig)
{
    //code for clean shutdown goes here: MUST be async-signal safe, such as:
    shouldStop = true;
}
...
int main()
{
    ...
    signal(SIGTERM, signalHandler); //this tells the OS to use your signal handler instead of default
    signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);  //can do it for other signals too
    ...
    //main work logic, which could be of form:
    while(!shouldStop) {
        ...
        if(someTerminatingCondition) break;
        ...
    }
    //cleanup including flushing
    ...
}
```

Be aware that if take this approach, you must make sure that your program does actually terminate after your custom handler is run (it is under no obligation to do so immediately, and can run clean-up logic as it sees fit). If it doesn't shut down, linux will not shut it down either so the SIGTERM will be 'ignored' from an outside perspective.

Note that by default the linux `kill` command sends a SIGTERM, invoking the behaviour above. If your program is running in the foreground and `Ctrl-C` is pressed, a SIGINT is sent instead, which is why you might want to handle that as well as per above.

Note also, the implementation suggested above takes care to be safe, in that no async logic is performed in the signal handler other than setting an atomic flag. This is important, as pointed out in the comments below. See the Async-signal safe section of [this page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for details of what is and isn't allowed.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, and I think I should implement it.  But it does not help now, as I have a *currently* running program.

Comment: Note that your "code for clean shutdown" must be async-signal-safe.  In general, flushing IO buffers is *not* async-signal-safe.  The only function calls guaranteed to be async-signal-safe are listed [about halfway down this page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html).  C++ IO will be somewhere on the spectrum between implementation-defined and undefined behavior.

Comment: Another solution is to attach a debugger (which would halt the program), then call `std::flush()` from it (e.g. `gdb` can evaluate expressions). Yet likewise, it's unsafe, as the program may be halted in some transient state. The safest way is to set a breakpoint somewhere outside any I/O and wait for it to be hit - so you know the I/O system is in a usable state.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I need to trigger the flush externally for stdout file redirect. The program is started like `./program > out.txt`. Is it possible to somehow get the reference of that file and call `fflush` externally (without modifiing the program of course)?